# Usage of comma before quotes

Tags: commas, quotations

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does a comma have to be used before a quotation?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/18867/does-a-comma-have-to-be-used-before-a-quotation)

Please let me know which of the two examples below are correct:

```
Example a: And he said "where are my chips?"  
Example b:And he said, "where are my chips?"
```

In b), I've placed a comma before the opening quote.

What is the correct usage? And if someone can point me to an external reference, that would be even better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called *direct speech*, and it does require a comma before the quotation. So, the second one is the right one. The opposite, that is,

> And he asked where were his chips.

is called *reported speech*.

Here’s a [link to Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_speech).

Comment: Yes, it appears that the comma is required. Here's a more reliable source that I've found: http://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/577/01/

Answer (score 1):

In the classical English grammar we were early taught in school, example b is correct. In current usage, I believe either is acceptable. In my writing, I've begun consciously to drop that comma.