# Is a comma needed before a quotation?

Tags: commas, quotations

> Sam developed an annual sweepstakes promotion entitled “The Free Gas Punt Return Game”.

Do I need a comma after *entitled* or not?

Comment: As Edwin Ashworth said in his answer, there's no hard and fast rule.  It depends on what flow you wish to impart to the text.

Comment: This is not a quotation. It is a name. Which only happens to be in quotes, and only because *you* put it in quotes, which are completely optional in the first place. You wouldn't write "girl named, Sarah", so don't write "promotion entitled, [title]", either. Simple as that.

Comment: It is not technically a quotation, but it is a title. One would place a book title or similar in quotation marks (if not adhering to the italicisation or other rule instead). Perhaps a promotion title does not need to be in quotation marks, or italicised, or anything else, but it isn't wrong.

Comment: Had you omitted the word "entitled," it would then take a comma: Sam developed an annual sweepstakes promotion, "The Free Gas Punt Return Game."

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/18867/does-a-comma-have-to-be-used-before-a-quotation?rq=1.

Answer (score 1):

[Grammar Monster](http://www.grammar-monster.com/lessons/quotation_(speech)_marks_colon_or_comma.htm) is better than it sounds:

> {DON'T WORRY:} IT'S NOT A HARD AND FAST RULE
>
> (re: introductory comma? colon? ....)
>
> The majority of people do not adhere to the guidelines regarding the
> use of commas and colons with quotations. Nowadays, it is acceptable
> to introduce a quotation with
>
> a comma,
>
> a colon
>
> – or nothing.
>
> In modern writing, the choice of punctuation [here] depends largely on
> the desired flow of the text (i.e., how much the writer wants the
> reader to pause).

And this refers in the first instance to direct speech, often treated with greater respect than other quotes.

- After thinking about this for several seconds she anxiously asked John, "He and Jim *are* coming here on Thursday?"
- Wishing she had less dull-witted politicians to deal with, she countered: "The vaccine won't be ready before the end of next year at the earliest."
- He shouted "I'm unarmed!" as soon as he was challenged.

.......

- Sam developed an annual sweepstakes promotion entitled 'The Free Gas Punt Return Game'.

Comment: But the example doesn't really "introduce" the quote; the quote is embedded in the sentence as a whole. And surely the purpose of a comma, or other punctuation, is syntactic, not a guide to good reading, ie, how long to pause .

Comment: There is still a lot of – I'll say debate – over the exact way to treat various levels of quotes. Some people treat the quote as the matrix sentence (or fragment), and the framing structure merely as a pragmatic marker. That obviously doesn't work in OP as the non-quote is heavily loaded with semantic content. I wouldn't use a comma in OP's example, for the reason you give, but I like the availability of all three above forms of punctuation for different examples. // The comma is not considered by many modern writers to have solely syntactic roles.

Comment: Oh indeed. Outside of the OP's specific example, there are many ways to precede a quotation, and having choice is great. Who are these "many modern writers"? I don't mean to sound derisive - I am genuinely interested in sources.

Comment: Pragmatic usages of commas (sometimes overlapping syntax-informing ones) are advocated [here](http://www.write.com/writing-resources-articles/general-writing/punctuation/mastering-the-art-of-comma-usage/commas-pauses-shifts-and-contrasted-coordinate-elements), [here](http://onewomanshop.com/author/ashley-brooks/) ('Use commas to create a pause if your breath units are getting too long') and [here](http://www.ucalgary.ca/uofc/eduweb/grammar/course/punctuation/3_4j.htm)

Comment: I agree that the first and third, as you say, overlap with informing syntax. The second I don't like at all, but that is an argument for another place. Appreciate the links though!

Comment: [Using the Comma:](http://www.ncl.ac.uk/langcen/facilities/guides/english/comma1-1.pdf) 
 'The comma is particularly useful, but it is one of the most frequently misused 
punctuation items. The first thing to understand is that the use of commas cannot be 
learned by rule. 
It is also true that the use of commas in the UK is sometimes different from that in the 
USA. Just remember that this is not an exact business. 
Using commas is as much a matter of taste, as of grammatical and syntactic 
accuracy.'

Comment: @nxx It really does "introduce" the quote (ie precede in the sentence and lay the framework for). 'Immediately precede' should cut out persnicketiness.

Comment: When it comes to the writing of English, experience casts suspicion on advice that begins, "Nowadays, ..." I do not know about you, but I don't like to be browbeaten into the latest writing fad. Modern prose is often better than prose of decades past, but "Nowadays, ..." is the refuge of the knave, the sophomore, who pretends to literary authority he or she has not earned. Grammar Monster's advice may happen to be good in this instance, but I don't think that I'll take that from them.

Answer (score 1):

No comma is needed.  Would you write, "Here is my brother named, John, and here is a photograph of my brother called, James?"  Or would you write, "Here is my brother named John, and here is a photograph of my brother James?"  If you are writing for a US readership, you'll want to tuck the period inside the quotation marks.

A late edit:  Of course, someone might consider the game in question to be a "work of art."  Doing so would allow the following:  Sam developed an annual sweepstakes promotion entitled *The Free Gas Punt Return Game*.  I like it.  In my initial read of the question I thought the quotation marks were being used to set-off the title as such, but seeing the game as a work of art solves some problems.

Comment: I don't think you are really addressing the OP's point here, and I think names used as interjections do get commas, on both sides of the pond. *Help me, Rhonda, help, help me, Rhonda.*

Comment: The "John" in "my brother John" is not a name being called for the purpose of getting his attention, while Rhonda is being called for help.  I'd say, "Ralph, you won't believe what my friend Susan just wrote."

Comment: The 'would you write' test is potentially very dangerous. For instance, all the following are in use: He wished her a merry Christmas. // He wished her merry Christmas // He wished her Merry Christmas. // He wished her, "Merry Christmas." // He wished her "Merry Christmas." Verbs used to introduce quotes and pseudo-quotes are many and various, and I'd say that a flexible approach is best. Though with your example, few would dream of inserting commas.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth  You are right.  It is a dangerous game.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, the quotation is not preceded by a speaker tag, is not even direct speech, and is part of the flow of your own sentence, so do not use a comma. The use of "entitled" doesn't change this, same as, to use Michael Owen Sartin's example, you would simply say "My brother is called John".

In case you are asking about preceding comma use more generally:

I can't find a good authoritative source to cite for this at the moment (anyone?), but dummies.com says [this](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-punctuate-quotations-in-statements.html):

> No comma separates the quotation from the rest of the sentence if the quotation doesn’t have a speaker tag.

And I like [these examples](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/577/01/):

> Mr. Johnson, who was working in his field that morning, said, "The alien spaceship appeared right before my own two eyes."

but

> Although Mr. Johnson has seen odd happenings on the farm, he stated that the spaceship "certainly takes the cake" when it comes to unexplainable activity.