# What to use? comma or colon?

Tags: punctuation

He bellowed outside: 'A disgrace! What have you got me?'

Or

He bellowed outside, 'A disgrace! What have you got me?'

Comma or Colon? Please help!

Answer (score 2):

This is dealt with already in SE :

> [Is there a comma needed before quotation?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/146173)

Where Edwin Ashworth states :

The majority of people do not adhere to the guidelines regarding the use of commas and colons with quotations. Nowadays, it is acceptable to introduce a quotation with a comma, a colon – or nothing.

In modern writing, the choice of punctuation depends largely on the desired flow of the text (i.e., how much the writer wants the reader to pause).

Comment: I think it would be a good idea to format your answer or indicate in some other way that it is copied from Edwin Ashworth's answer to the question in the link you provide. Alternatively, you could provide the link in a comment below the question.

Comment: @Shoe Thank you. Next time I will add  the link as a comment.

Comment: Next time, you can avoid my downvote by correctly close-voting the question as a duplicate instead of repeating an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should refer to other books.

"Jim!" A man bellowed outside. "Which way did they go?"  -Heat of the Moment

Whispering Bob Harris bellowed, 'Service please!'  -What's Up With Jody Barton?

He bellowed: There is no choice!  -Legal Deposit of 13 New Titles

... he bellowed furiously: "Firmin! Firmin! Charmerace! Charmerace!"  -Arsene Lupin

"You just heard my thoughts!" I bellowed.  -Salphos: Prince of Delnot

Answer (score 0):

My answer is limited to the issue of which punctuation mark to use following a reporting verb that introduces direct speech.

It seems that the comma is the more common choice. But two of the sources below indicate contexts in which the colon may be preferred.

*Practical English Usage* (p463), states:

> A comma is generally used between a reporting expression and a piece
>   of direct speech.
>
> - He said, 'There's no way we can help her'.

*Cambridge Grammar of English* states (p845):

> Commas are used to indicate that direct speech is following.

*The Cambridge Guide to English Usage* (p455) notes:

> According to an older convention, a quotation is preceded by a comma. ... 
>   This is still quite common practice in novels, though a simple space
>   may serve the same purpose. ...  In newspapers and magazines there's a strong tendency to use a colon
>   before quoted material.

*Collins Cobuild English Usage* (p553) says:

> If you put something like *he said* in front of direct speech, you put a
>   comma in front of the direct speech. ... People sometimes put a colon in front of direct speech, especially to indicate that what follows is important.
>
> - I said: 'Perhaps your father is right.'

So maybe in the present example of bellowing, the colon could be considered the stronger choice.

If you do a search on a string of words that commonly indicate direct speech, you can then scroll through the hits and see whether the comma or colon is more common.

For example, a quick scan of the first 20 pages of the string "*She said I*" indicates that the comma is approximately 2-3 times more common than the colon. 
https://www.google.de/search?q=%22she+said+I%22&ei=qWfaWY-FNoyKgAai75K4Dg&start=170&sa=N&biw=1280&bih=893

There are also several examples of direct speech where neither the comma nor the colon is used, but simply a space.