# Should a comma be used to separate the subject and verb from a quote?

Tags: punctuation

> Tom exclaimed "This is going to be great!"

> Samantha asked ‘How long will it take to get there?’

Is a comma needed in these sentences, if the sentences have a question mark and an exclamation mark in direct speech?
[The Free Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Quotation-Marks.htm) says "don't use".

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140272/discussion-on-question-by-user466929-question-mark-and-exclamation-point-used-in).

Comment: It doesn't specifically say "don't use" on the page you link - please quote the relevant passage that you think says that. They say "If we are quoting an entire sentence, we set the quotation apart with one or two commas" and have several examples that use commas, so I'm not sure how you infer "don't use" from that.

Answer (score 0):

There is no precise guide on this question. The best I could find (https://www.quickanddirtytips.com/articles/when-to-use-commas-before-quotations/) says that comma may be used if the clause within quotation is syntactically independent.

In your example sentences, commas may be preferred.

This question ([Is a comma needed before a quotation?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/146173/is-a-comma-needed-before-a-quotation)) asks a similar question.